# Exec commands on kubernetes pods with root access

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes

I have one pod running with name 'jenkins-app-2843651954-4zqdp'. I want to install few softwares temporarily on this pod. How can I do this?

I am trying this- `kubectl exec -it  jenkins-app-2843651954-4zqdp  -- /bin/bash`
and then running apt-get install commands but since the user I am accessing with doesn't have sudo access I am not able to run commands

Comment: you could add this to pod, but after exit it will be gone. Better alter the docker image and add soft

Answer (score 125):

- Use `kubectl describe pod ...` to find the node running your Pod and the container ID (`docker://...`)
- SSH into the node
- Run `docker exec -it -u root CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash`

Comment: how to ssh into the node in this case?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer myself. I am using google cloud. The command to ssh into node is:
gcloud compute instances list
gcloud compute ssh <your_instance_name>

Comment: should be `docker exec -it -u root ID /bin/bash`

Comment: If it helps anyone, ID above means docker container id. AFAIK, kubectl won't show  the correct docker container id. We have to use docker ps to get the correct docker container id.

Comment: Kinda obsolete answer now, considering that Docker has been deprecated in K8s version 1.20.

Comment: no ssh is needed you can directly get the pod id  and execute 
``docker exec -it -u root <ID> /bin/sh``

Answer (score 33):

There are some plugins for kubectl that may help you achieve this: https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins

One of the plugins called, 'ssh', will allow you to exec as root user by running (for example) 
`kubectl ssh -u root -p nginx-0`

Comment: Super! I can't believe this plugin hasn't become as popular as it deserves. However, the `krew` plugin for `kubectl exec-as ...` doesn't seem to be keeping up with the latest Kubernetes. See my comment in the follow-up answer below.

Comment: This plugin is not working with a modern k8s version, like 1.22 for example, that is using containerd. See https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins/issues/40.

Answer (score 19):

Adding to the answer from [henning-jay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72559556/1883971), when using **containerd** as runtime.

get containerID via

> kubectl get pod *<podname>* -o
> jsonpath="{.status.containerStatuses[].containerID}" | sed 's,.*//,,'

containerID will be something like
7e328fc6ac5932fef37f8d771fd80fc1a3ddf3ab8793b917fafba317faf1c697

lookup the node for pod

> kubectl get pod *<podname>* -o wide

on node, trigger runc - since its invoked by containerd, the --root has to be changed

> runc --root /run/containerd/runc/k8s.io/ exec -t -u 0 *<containerID>* sh

Answer (score 13):

Building on @jordanwilson230's answer he also developed a bash-script called `exec-as` which uses Docker-in-Docker to accomplish this: https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins/blob/krew/kubectl-exec-as

When installed via kubectl plugin manager [krew](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew) → `kubectl krew install exec-as` you can simply

```
kubectl exec-as -u <username> <podname> -- /bin/bash
```

This only works in Kubernetes clusters which allow priviledged containers.

Comment: Maybe this `exec-as` plugin hasn't been maintained lately? It doesn't work on AWS EKS v1.21. It simply hangs there till `error: timed out waiting for the condition`. However, the original `kubectl ssh -u root ...` works as shown in @jordanwilson230's original answer above. That makes me think that the `exec-as` plugin version is falling behind of that of `ssh` plugin.

Comment: This also seems to only work on clusters that use docker runtime, or at least it didn't work on one that uses containerd.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using a modern Kubernetes version it's likely running containerd instead of docker for it's container runtime.

To exec as root you must have SSH access and SUDO access to the node on which the container is running.

1. Get the container id of the pod. Example:

```bash
 kubectl get pod cassandra-0 -n cassandra -o jsonpath="{.status.containerStatuses[].containerID}" | sed 's/.*\/\///'
8e1f2e5907087b5fd55d98849fef640ca73a5ca04db2e9fc0b7d1497ff87aed9
```

2. Use `runc` to exec as root. Example:

```bash
sudo runc --root /run/containerd/runc/k8s.io/ exec -t -u 0 8e1f2e5907087b5fd55d98849fef640ca73a5ca04db2e9fc0b7d1497ff87aed9 sh
```

Comment: I am unable to install packages after getting access to the container due to `E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (30: Read-only file system)`. Any way around this?

Answer (score 12):

For my case, I was in need for root access (or sudo) to container to give the `chown` permission to a specific mount path.

I cannot SSH to machine because I designed my infrastructure to be fully automated with Terraform without any manual access.

Instead, I found that `initContainers` does the job:

```
  initContainers:
    - name: volume-prewarming
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:0 {{ .Values.persistence.mountPath }}"]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        mountPath: {{ .Values.persistence.mountPath }}
```

I've also created a whole course about [Production grade running kubernetes on AWS using EKS](https://www.udemy.com/course/aws-eks-kubernetes/?referralCode=C8E1E37FB75A998FAE09)

Comment: Hi Abdennour. I am running through a similar issue, however I am using a git-sync sidecar  that I mount. Once the sidecar is mounted the owner of the volume becomes root. I have added a question here if you can help : )  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65457870/how-can-i-avoid-permission-denied-errors-when-mounting-a-container-into-my-dep

Answer (score 12):

Just in case you come across to look for an answer for **minikube**, the `minikube ssh` command can actually work with `docker` command together here, which makes it fairly easy:

1. Find the container ID:

   ```
   $ minikube ssh docker container ls
   ```
2. Add the `-u 0` option to docker command (*quote is necessary for the whole docker command*):

   ```
   $ minikube ssh "docker container exec -it -u 0 <Container ID> /bin/bash"
   ```

NOTE: this is NOT for Kubernetes in general, it works for **minikube** only. While I feel we need the root access quit a lot in local development environment, it's worth to mention it in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is working on AKS, follow these steps:

- Identify the pod that is running the container
- Identity the node that is running that pod (`kubectl describe pod -n <namespace> <pod_name> | grep "Node:"`, or look for it on Azure portal)
- [SSH to AKS the cluster node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh#create-the-ssh-connection)

Once you are inside a node, perform these commands to get into the container:

- `sudo su` (you must get root access to use `docker` commands)
- `docker exec -it -u root ID /bin/bash` (to get the container id, use `docker container ps`)

Answer (score 3):

In k8s deployment configuration, you can set to run the container as `root`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  template: 
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: my-image
    name: my-app
    ...
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      runAsUser: 0
```

Notice that `runAsUser: 0` property.
Then connect to the POD/container as usual and you will be authenticated as `root` from the beginning.

Comment: Insecure. This would run the main service as root. I guess the question was about just debugging/administering as root.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo, yep, the question was about a temporary solution for installing extra software, then after the debugging is done that change should be reverted back.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE k8s v1.27.4 2023-10: (After switch from DOCKER to CONTAINERS)

Lets sumarize what I found here in posts, comments and links.
This works for me:

```
# First get list of nodes:
kubectl get nodes                                                                   
$ NAME                 STATUS     ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
$ node-control-plane   Ready      control-plane,master   4d16h   v1.21.1
$ node-worker          NotReady   <none>                 4d16h   v1.21.1
$ node-worker2         Ready      <none>                 4d16h   v1.21.1

# Start pod based on ubuntu which will connect direct inside the node:
kubectl debug node/node-worker -it --image=ubuntu
$ Creating debugging pod node-debugger-ip-10-0-5-223.eu-west-2.compute.internal-6gs8d with container debugger on node ip-10-0-5-223.eu-west-2.compute.internal.
$ If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
root@ip-10-0-5-223:/# 

# Now you are connected on debug pod and content of node filesystem is at /host
# Lets chroot there:
root@ip-10-0-5-223:/# chroot /host
sh-4.2# 

# Now you are connected inside node, so you can check used space (df -h), running processes (top) or install things with yum (yum install htop mc -y)

# Lets get root access to some pod on this node, you need to find its CONTAINER ID:
sh-4.2/ docker ps 
OR
sh-4.2/ ctr -n k8s.io containers list
#or "docker ps | less" then move around with arrows to find  correct CONTAINER ID and quit with q
$ CONTAINER ID    IMAGE     COMMAND         CREATED             STATUS             PORTS     NAMES
$ 0d82a8768c1e    centos    "/bin/bash"     2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                 k8s_prometheus-ip-11-2-6-218.compute.internal-alksdjf_default_asldkfj-lsadkfj-lsafjdk

sh-4.2/ docker exec -it -u root 0d82a8768c1e /bin/bash
OR
sh-4.2/ ctr -n k8s.io tasks exec --exec-id 1 0d82a8768c1e /bin/bash
(you can validate if container have running task by: ctr -n k8s.io tasks ls)
(if /bin/bash fails, try /bin/sh)
$ root@centos:/# 
#and here we are, inside pod with root account - good luck.
```

Sources: [Open a shell to a node using kubectl](https://medium.com/@the_good_guy/get-shell-access-to-pods-nodes-in-kubernetes-using-kubectl-1d8fc10e89eb#57b8) and [post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805365/9602905)

Answer (score 2):

To login as different i use exec-as plugin in kubernetes here are the steps you can follow

> Make sure git is installed

**Step : 1 Install Krew plugin**

```
  begin
  set -x; set temp_dir (mktemp -d); cd "$temp_dir" &&
  set OS (uname | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') &&
  set ARCH (uname -m | sed -e 's/x86_64/amd64/' -e 's/\(arm\)\(64\)\?.*/\1\2/' -e 's/aarch64$/arm64/') &&
  set KREW krew-$OS"_"$ARCH &&
  curl -fsSLO "https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew/releases/latest/download/$KREW.tar.gz" &&
  tar zxvf $KREW.tar.gz &&
  ./$KREW install krew &&
  set -e KREW; set -e temp_dir
end
```

**Step : 2 Install exec-as**

```
kubectl krew install exec-as
```

**Step : 3 Try with root or different user**

```
kubectl exec-as -u root frontend-deployment-977b8fd4c-tb5pz
```

> WARNING: You installed plugin "prompt" from the krew-index plugin repository.
> These plugins are not audited for security by the Krew maintainers.
> Run them at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for providing an easy way to use this plugin, but it has been recommended in previous answers before. And it's not working with modern k8s using containerd instead of docker.

Answer (score 2):

Working with kubernetes 1.21, none of the docker and kubectl-plugin approaches worked for me. (since k8s 1.21 uses cri-o as container runtime).

What did work for me was using runc:

- get containerID via

> kubectl get pod   -o
> jsonpath="{.status.containerStatuses[].containerID}" | sed
> 's/.*////'

- containerID is
  something like

> 4ed493495241b061414b94425bb03b682534241cf19776f8809aeb131fa5a515

- get node pod is running on

> ```
> kubectl describe pod <podname>  | grep Node:
>     Node:         mynode.cluster.cloud.local/1.1.148.63
> ```

- ssh into node
- on node, run (might have to use sudo):

> runc  exec -t -u 0 containerID sh

so something like:

> runc  exec -t -u 0 4ed493495241b061414b94425bb03b682534241cf19776f8809aeb131fa5a515 sh

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine found this tool: https://github.com/ssup2/kpexec

> It runs a highly privileged container on the same node as the target container and joins into the namespaces of the target container (IPC, UTS, PID, net, mount)
>
> [...]
> kpexec now supports the following container runtimes.
>
> - containerd
> - CRI-O
> - Docker
>
> [...]
> The cnsenter pod must be created with hostPID and Privileged Option

To get root you could run something like

```bash
kpexec -it  jenkins-app-2843651954-4zqdp  -- /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following

1. Install https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/
2. Install https://github.com/ssup2/kpexec into kubectl using krew by running `kubectl krew install pexec`.
3. [Assuming your kubectl is pointing to correct cluster], Connect to pod/container using `kubectl pexec -it -n <namespace> <pod name> [-c <container name>] -- bash`

Additional info:

If target container is is Debian, if you want to install any generic tools like `htop` etc, if no softwares were pulled before, you 1st need to run `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get install htop`

Comment: This works very well, even on systems where you DO NOT have `ssh` access to the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

That's all well and good, but what about new versions of kubernetes that use containerd?
using `nerdctl exec -uroot -ti 817d52766254 sh`
there is no full-fledged root, part of the system in this read-only mode

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the node name, another way to get ssh into it is using:

```
kubectl debug node/<node_name> -it --image=<image>
```

eg:

```
kubectl debug node/my_node -it --image=ubuntu
```

and after that:

```
chroot /host
```

[usage example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWDag.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when using **k3s v1.27.6+k3s1**, I found that the `runc` command was not available. Instead, I utilized the `ctr` command. Here's how you can do it:

Firstly, you need to identify the container ID. This can be done using the following command:

```bash
kubectl -n wordpress describe pod <podname> | grep 'Container ID:'
```

For instance, you might get an output similar to this:

```bash
    Container ID:   containerd://aaff66aaaeca129eab1b8e51ebf391fd59191f41db5540c1e8af65675737073e
```

Once you have the container ID, you can use the `ctr` command to execute commands within the container. Here's an example:

```bash
sudo k3s ctr task exec -t --exec-id myshell --user root aaff66aaaeca129eab1b8e51ebf391fd59191f41db5540c1e8af65675737073e bash
```

In this command, replace `aaff66aaaeca129eab1b8e51ebf391fd59191f41db5540c1e8af65675737073e` with your own container ID. This will allow you to execute commands within your specific container.

Answer (score -9):

- `docker container ls` to find container ID
- `docker exec -it -u root ID /bin/bash`

Comment: The question is about kubernetes cluster. This solution does not work for remote cluster.

Comment: But it works perfectly for local cluster. Upvoted it.

Answer (score -29):

We can exec into `kubernetes` pod through the following command.

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty pod-name -n namespace-name -- /bin/bash
```

Comment: The post is asking about executing commands as root. I don't understand what you mean.