# connecting to Kubernetes kops pod using docker deamon

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kops

I created Kubernetes cluster with kops (on AWS), and i want to access to one of my nodes as a root.According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793382/exec-commands-on-kubernetes-pods-with-root-access), it's possible only with Docker command.
When i type `docker image ls` i'm getting nothing. When i was using minikube i solved this issue with `minikube docker-env` and from output i just copied last line into new CMD line `@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i`
(I'm using Widnows 10) and using above procedure, after typing `docker image ls` or `docker image ps` i was able to see all minikube pods. Is there any way to do the same for pods created with kops ?

I'm able to do it connecting to Kubernetes node, install docker on it, and then i can connect to pod specifying -u root switch, but i wonder is it possible to do the same from host machine (Windows 10 in my case)

Comment: Just to be sure, the `docker image ls` command is done on your AWS node (not on your windows machine) ?

Comment: You just need to `ssh` to the node.  Docker isn't involved at all.

Comment: `docker image ls` is running on my Windows machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. A pod is an abstraction created and managed by kubernetes. The docker daemon has no idea to what is a pod. You can only see the containers using docker command. But then again, you wont be able to tell which container is associated to which pod.

Answered by @Marc ABOUCHACRA

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. So I'm going to give some general info here based on this scenario : *You've created a K8S cluster on AWS using Kops*

### I want to access one of my AWS node as root

This has nothing to do with **kops** nor it has with **Docker**. This is basic AWS management. You need to check on your AWS console management to get all the info to connect to your node.

### I want to see all the docker image from my windows laptop

Again, this has nothing to do with **kops**. Kops is a Kubernetes distribution. In Kubernetes, the smallest units of computing that can be managed is the **pod**. You cannot manage *directly* docker containers or images with kubernetes.
So if you want to see your docker images, you'll need to somehow connect to your AWS node and then execute

```sh
docker image ls
```

In fact, that's what you're doing with your minikube example. You're just executing the docker command on the VM managed by minikube.

More info on what's a pod [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/)

### I want to see all the pods created with kops

Well, assuming that you've succesfully configured your system to access AWS with kops (more info on that [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md)), then you'll just have to directly execute any `kubectl` command. For example, to list all the pods located in the `kube-system` namespace :

```sh
kubectl -n kube-system get po
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: i want, to get all pods using docker command (docker is installed on my Windows 10 machine, i also installed Docker on Windows 10) from AWS cluster, without making SSH to AWS node and installing docker on that node. I can achieve the same when, instead of AWS cluster, i'm using minikube. I just want to know is it possible or not.

Comment: That is not possible.  
A **pod** is an abstraction created and managed by kubernetes. The docker daemon has no idea to what is a pod. You can only see the containers using docker command. But then again, you wont be able to tell which container is associated to which pod.