# root password of an public image kubesphere/elasticsearch-oss:6.7.0-1

Tags: docker

kubesphere/elasticsearch-oss:6.7.0-1 image from Docker hub need to provide password for root account when I want to use root account to install some tools. How can I get or change its password?

```
sh-4.2$ su root  
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

Comment: Make your own image. Don’t do this in runtime, your changes will be lost when you recreate the container. A container is not a VM.

Comment: I think you can refer to this article [Exec commands on kubernetes pods with root access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793382/exec-commands-on-kubernetes-pods-with-root-access) to exec as root in K8s

Answer (score 0):

Kubesphere support using external ES, you can change the ES url to any ES cluster you want. The in-cluster ES is not for production purpose.

And yes, it's not recommended to install plugin inside docker.

Comment: Care to explain why it is not recommended to install plugin inside docker?