# How can I avoid `Permission denied` Errors when mounting a container into my deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dbt

#### Background

I am currently deploying [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) using Helm (using [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow) chart). I am using a [git-sync sidecar](https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync) to mount the SQL & Python files which Airflow will need to have access to to be able to execute scripts/files.

#### What seems not to work

Once I am done with deploying my container, it seems that my Airflow user is unable to use the files (that have been mounted by the git sidecar), and exits with error (this error happens for all files that have been mounted not only target):

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'target'
```

#### What I have tried

My docker container for the deployment looks like:

```
FROM apache/airflow:1.10.14-python3.8

USER root

# apt deps
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
           nano \
           gcc \
           python3-dev \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Use airflow user for pip installs and other things.
USER airflow

# Additional requirements for Airflow
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

# Creating folder for logs
RUN mkdir -p /opt/airflow/dbt_logs
RUN pip install dbt==0.18.1 

EXPOSE 8081
```

Running `ls -ld */` (in `/opt/airflow` ) in the **scheduler** container I get:

```
airflow@airflow-scheduler-58c7cb87b8-8nk6f:/opt/airflow$ ls -ld */
drwxrwsrwx 5    1000    1000 41 Dec 26 16:02 dags/
drwxr-xr-x 2 airflow airflow  6 Dec 26 14:10 dbt_logs/
drwxrwxr-x 1 airflow root    52 Dec 26 16:02 logs/
```

And running `ls -ld */` (in `/opt/airflow` ) in the **web server** container I get:

```
airflow@airflow-web-7f8df9457-7n2dp:/opt/airflow$ ls -ld */
drwxrwsrwx 5 root    nogroup 41 Dec 26 14:20 dags/
drwxr-xr-x 1 airflow airflow 21 Dec 26 14:41 dbt_logs/
drwxrwxr-x 1 airflow root    23 Dec 26 14:20 logs/
```

This is how the structure of the dbt folder looks like withing my dags dir:

```
airflow@airflow-scheduler-6cdc985b9b-ssmhx:/opt/airflow/dags/dbt/dw$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1000 3061 Dec 27 09:00 README.md
drwxr-sr-x 2 root 1000   22 Dec 27 09:00 analysis
drwxr-sr-x 2 root 1000   22 Dec 27 09:00 data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1000 1852 Dec 27 09:00 dbt_project.yml
drwxr-sr-x 2 root 1000  214 Dec 27 09:00 macros
drwxr-sr-x 3 root 1000   21 Dec 27 09:00 models
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1000  141 Dec 27 09:00 packages.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1000  842 Dec 27 09:00 profiles.yml
drwxr-sr-x 2 root 1000   22 Dec 27 09:00 snapshots
drwxr-sr-x 2 root 1000   22 Dec 27 09:00 tests
```

Worth mentioning that I seem not to be able to create files within the dbt dir with the airflow user (permission denied)

It seems to me that once the volume is mounted its owner becomes the root user. How can I provide the Airflow user with the ability to access the mounted git repository?

Happy to provide additional details if needed

Comment: are you using `emptyDir` volume?

Comment: Hi @ItayB. I am mounting using the git-sync sidecar. I am not sure if it implements an emptyDir volume (how can I check?). Once the mount happens, the directory that is mounted becomes owned by the root user and not the Airflow user, and I can’t have full access the mounted directory.

Comment: you can verify that in your helm chart. BTW, why do you need `git` in your airflow image if you're using git-sync in a separate container?

Comment: To my understanding from reading here (https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/0f40ffe1c1a2949463ff9c59549b4fdf75391cd1/charts/airflow/templates/scheduler/scheduler-deployment.yaml#L141) is that it is not using an EmptyDir implementation. I think the git part is useless now because I implemented the the git sync, so probably will remove it

Comment: where did you mount it in the scheduler container? is it within `/usr/local/airflow` ? what's the `pwd` where you run `ls -ld` ?

Comment: @ItayB I have updated my question with more details to answer your questions. It was mounted by the helm chart (so I did not manually do the mounting but it was through the interface of the helm chart). Please let me know if I can provide more details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226455/discussion-between-alt-f4-and-itayb).

Comment: airflow-web doesn't need git-sync & doesn't need the dags. He will get it from the scheduler

Comment: @ItayB that is correct

Comment: is it solve your "Permission denied" issue?

Comment: I am still getting permissions denied as the owner of the mounted volume is still root. I have managed to run an InitContainer with `["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/airflow/dags/"]` command. That changes the dag folder's ownership to 1000 (now trying to figure out if that will help me)

Comment: I think you're in the wrong direction. The last 3 chars in `drwxrwsrwx` state that **all** can read/write/execute the dag folder. I still don't understand what `target` is? directory? file?

Comment: I think what is happening is that DBT (which is ran through the airflow user) tries to create a directory called `target` , and it fails to do so. In the dbt yaml file definition it reads: `target-path: "target"  # directory which will store compiled SQL files`

Comment: I have also updated my question with details on how my dbt dir looks like. I can't create files there with my airflow user

Comment: I'm not familiar with `dbt` but sounds like this is your problem. Can you create a simple DAG example **without** the `dbt` to isolate the problem you're facing? (One simple python file)

Comment: @ItayB there seems to be no issue running a Python file or dbt itself. The problem seems to happen is when DBT tries to create files within it's own directory (within the dags folder). When I set the paths for these files to be outside the dags folder (owned by airflow user) that seems to work. So it seems that the airflow user not being able to create files within DBT's directory is the issue. (will update as I have more insights)

Comment: check your image user linux namespace  PSP, SCC,.. so on

Comment: Have you tried adding [security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) and setting fsGroup?

Comment: @alt-f4 were you able to solve this? I'm hitting exactly the same problem... any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @alt-f4 were u able to resolve this issue? i am on the same boat now