# access pod as root user

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm accessing k8 pod using this command:

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty forms-service-cf95d4c9b-zgv9t -n staging -- /bin/bash
```

The problem is that the user is not root.

How can I access the container as root? can't find any option other than rebuilding it which is not what I want:/

Comment: did you try [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793382/exec-commands-on-kubernetes-pods-with-root-access)?

Comment: all those are not working in kubectl default, they are all users plugins that need to beinstalled. I't weird that kubectl can't provide root access to pod

Comment: What do you hope to do in a root shell in a container?  Pods are deleted fairly routinely (whenever the underlying deployment is updated, for example) and so it's not a great idea to make detailed manual updates inside a running pod.  If you just need to debug the image contents, `docker run` locally might be easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exec commands on kubernetes pods with root access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793382/exec-commands-on-kubernetes-pods-with-root-access)

Comment: @NoamYizraeli this is the same as the first solution, works on minikube or third party installtions, which are not desired

Comment: what k8s version are you using? how are you verifying the current user after entering the container? (please attach terminal output and answers as edits to the question)

Comment: @NoamYizraeli it's irrelevant, k8s doesn't give the option unless u use 3rd pary libraries. only Docker command can provide this option. Cheers